# Spark Dataset[T] select typed transformation usage

Tags: apache-spark

Can some one explain me the usage of Dataset[T] select Typed transformations.
What is meaning of 5 columns. There is another overloaded method of select with 4 columns also 3,2,1 columns respectively.
It means we can select only 5 columns from Dataset[T] ? Can someone give example.

```
def select[U1, U2, U3, U4, U5]
(c1: TypedColumn[T, U1], 
c2: TypedColumn[T, U2], 
c3: TypedColumn[T, U3], 
c4: TypedColumn[T, U4], 
c5: TypedColumn[T, U5]): Dataset[(U1, U2, U3, U4, U5)]
Returns a new Dataset by computing the given Column expressions for each element.
```

Spark API Doc [Link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)

```
def select[U1](c1: TypedColumn[T, U1]): Dataset[U1]
Returns a new Dataset by computing the given Column expression for each element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great question!

If you look closely at the docs link you added, you see that there is another `select` method. Its function signature is this one:

```scala
def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame
```

Thanks to this function, we're able to select as many columns as we like. But there is a slight difference between the methods you mentioned and this one: its input/output types.

- In the methods you mentioned, the inputs are strongly typed. The method is generic and the output is a strongly typed **Dataset**.
- In the method I mentioned, the inputs are just strings (column names). The method is not generic and the output is a **Dataframe**.

Let's see this in action:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

case class MyCol1(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol2(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol3(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol4(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol5(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol6(a: Int, b: String)
case class MyCol7(a: Int, b: String)
case class TotalClass( col1: MyCol1, col2: MyCol2, col3: MyCol3, col4: MyCol4, col5: MyCol5, col6: MyCol6, col7: MyCol7)

val ds = Seq(
  ( MyCol1(5, "a"), MyCol2(5, "a"), MyCol3(5, "a"), MyCol4(5, "a"), MyCol5(5, "a"), MyCol6(5, "a"), MyCol7(5, "a") ),
  ( MyCol1(5, "a"), MyCol2(5, "a"), MyCol3(5, "a"), MyCol4(5, "a"), MyCol5(5, "a"), MyCol6(5, "a"), MyCol7(5, "a") ),
  ( MyCol1(5, "a"), MyCol2(5, "a"), MyCol3(5, "a"), MyCol4(5, "a"), MyCol5(5, "a"), MyCol6(5, "a"), MyCol7(5, "a") )
).toDF( "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7").as[TotalClass]

// Selecting 1 column
ds.select($"col1".as[MyCol1])
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyCol1] = [a: int, b: string]

// Selecting 5 columns
ds.select($"col1".as[MyCol1], $"col2".as[MyCol2], $"col3".as[MyCol3], $"col4".as[MyCol4], $"col5".as[MyCol5])
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(MyCol1, MyCol2, MyCol3, MyCol4, MyCol5)] = [col1: struct<a: int, b: string>, col2: struct<a: int, b: string> ... 3 more fields]

// Selecting 6 columns
ds.select($"col1".as[MyCol1], $"col2".as[MyCol2], $"col3".as[MyCol3], $"col4".as[MyCol4], $"col5".as[MyCol5], $"col6".as[MyCol6])
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: struct<a: int, b: string>, col2: struct<a: int, b: string> ... 4 more fields]
```

This confirms our suspicion! We are able to query 1-5 columns by using the strongly typed `select` method. Once we try to select more than that, we fall back to the method that gives a Dataframe as output.

Hope this helps!